# Finding alternatives to rogues in campaigns

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, class

In a nutshell, I'm looking to join a game, but it seems that the type of character that I play often (rogue), has been done by everyone else in the group. Are there any other classes or sub-classes that would be a good fit for someone that usually plays rogue type players?

EDIT: To elaborate on what I enjoy about the role, mainly the way that you don't need to be relying on strength or magic to survive, but by guile, deceit, and striking when the opportunity presents themselves. Plus I find them easier to play as more evil/neutral characters, which is a great change of pace (if I do other classes, I'm usually in the good realm, albeit chaotic).

Comment: Also, welcome to the site, mate! :)

Comment: @canadiancreed It would help if you specify what you enjoy about playing a rogue, whether it's stealth/scouting, striking/sneak attacking, skill monkey work, or what...

Comment: What do you mean that everyone else is a rogue?  Does Assassin or Ranger count as rogue?

Comment: @gmnoob to me at least, an assassin would, (and one does exist) but a ranger would not.

Comment: By "has been done" you mean all the existing characters are rogues or variants on rogues?  Sounds like a good reason to also be a rogue to me... Or a rogue-god cleric, or a sneaky monk, or anything else that looks like a rogue from 30' away.

Comment: It isn't an answer, so just a comment: It sounds like another rogue would fit right in. The party would be all rogues. A rogue's gallery. :-) Why not? Rogues can specialize enough to fill a lot of different class roles: even magic and healing with Use Magic Device.

Comment: @zan lynx that would be pretty humourous, but for my chars, I always like to add some diversity to the group. I'm silly like that. That and I cant' seem to play the stereotypical fighter very well, find it quite boring.

Comment: Some good answers everyone, and thanks for replying. Made my job of choosing a "correct one" hard, but definitely impressed me with the amount of community action here on this site.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may also enjoy a **Bard**.

Though they are often dismissed in 3.5, Bards can actually do some pretty awesome stuff.

I planned out a sneaky/trickster Bard for a campaign that never happened:

- His spell choices were **illusion magic, grease, expeditious retreat, etc**.  Almost all spells could be used to avoid or escape direct combat.  And if it was inevitable, you could always drop a grease slick between you and fire arrows while they slid around.
- He had a short sword and a bow, and wore light armor.  As a side note, I believe Bards **suffer no spell failure penalty due to light armor!**
- His skills were **sneak, search, listen, etc**.

The music component isn't all there is to Bards :) .

Comment: Think I'll give this a try. Never really thought of bards for the typical reasons (aka "dont' they just go around and sing?"), but will give them a try.

Comment: Bards always remind me of a movie 'The Gamers 2'.  It contains the line "quickly, hide behind the pile of dead bards!".  Pure awesomeness

Comment: +1 Social skills, lore, spells, sneaking, bards are a useful utility package

Answer (score 22):

Reading your description it sounds like you are interested in playing certain personality traits more so than the specific rogue skills and abilities.  My advice is to play any class you want, giving your character those mannerisms you enjoy.

- Instead of the fighter with 18 strength, a greatsword and platemail consider playing one whose highest stat is dexterity, wears leather armor and likes throwing daggers from the shadows.
- Instead of a wizard who throws fireballs and summons demons play a wizard who uses invisibility, silence, sleep, etc to achieve his goals.
- Skip the lawful-stupid paladin stereotype and play a weak one that became a paladin after growing up in the underbelly of a large city. He wants to fix the injustices he saw but knows that kicking in doors and telling the full, unadulterated truth will get him nowhere.  So he relies on white lies and watching from shadows, waiting for the right time to bring down evil, constantly walking a fine line between the ideals he swore to uphold as a paladin and the real world that he's required to live in.

In short, **craft a background for your character that suits what you enjoy playing**.  There's no need to constrain yourself to one or two classes for that, as any class can support any personality.

Comment: Small Critique, Paladins can't lie at all, or they'll lose their powers. Now they can refuse to answer questions, but if they reply it must be the truth. (Depending GM lenience as well).

Comment: @Cthos: There's a prestige class in Complete Scoundrel that mitigates that, though. Grey Guardian or something like that, IIRC.

Comment: It's this one, http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/prc/20070320, But I think it just makes it cheaper for you to Atone, but I dunno, I don't have the book handy.

Comment: @Cthos Paladin's only lose their powers if they willingly commit an evil act. Lying is not in itself an evil act... and in some situations NOT lying results in an evil act. I should also point out that I said paladin's should use white lies. A white lie is not actually a lie, it is just omitting some information. The paladin is still technically telling the truth.

Comment: Eh, that depends on how lenient your GM is though: "Additionally, a paladin’s code requires that she respect legitimate authority, act with honor (**not lying**, not cheating, not using poison, and so forth)" and "A paladin who ceases to be lawful good, who willfully commits an evil act, or who grossly **violates the code of conduct** loses all paladin spells and abilities". http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/paladin.htm. If the GM is cool with you omitting information then by all means. Some of them however are not at all, and if you lie at all powers gone.

Comment: You didn't quite bold that last line correctly: or who **grossly violates the code of conduct**.  I tend to take grossly as meaning a flagrant, extereme violation of the conduct; though I can also agree with those GM's who allow paladins 144 violations of the code of conduct. Nevertheless I would be shocked at a GM who uses a single lie as an excuse to strip the paladin of their powers.

Answer (score 5):

**Factotum or Binder**

The [factotum](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19871722/The_Factotum_Handbook) is even more a "jack of all trades" than a rogue. While less "sneak attacky" than a rogue, they can play in much the same way and are even better at skills. They're a very acceptable complement to rogues, being able to be a generalist to cover any skill-gaps the rogues leave.

[Binder](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19871830/Consolidated_Binder_Handbook) is a strange bird. But the remarkable versatility of some binds can present a "similar circumvent the challenge" mechanic. Their main appeal, to me, is the ability to say "I'm going to play an *X*" today, and generally be able to pull it off. That way, you can cover the holes that appear in your party's composition as the situation merits, also evoking the "jack of all trades" elements of a rogue. Malphas in particular, makes most rogues [redacted] with envy. It's an incredible complement to a rogue party for its scouting capabilities. You, quite literally, have your own UAV to fly around. Naberius is fantastic for the "I'm going to be talky today." and the disguise self capabilities enable incredibly fun bluff based sneaks. It *is* a non-trivially complex class, though. Make sure to read the handbook before jumping in. If you were going roguish-binder, I'd dip my first level in rogue or factotum for the skills (and then grab Able Learner) Illumians also present a fantastic synergy, as they have dialable synergies as well.

Leave a comment if you were looking for other domains that the rogue enjoys, and I'll add to this post based on the requirements you describe.

Comment: On Factotums not being "sneak attacky", there's actually a skill called "Iajutsu Focus" from Oriental Adventures that Factotums can *technically* take (depending on how literally your DM construes "ALL skills as class skills") that more or less gives you sneak attack as a skill check with better rolls meaning more damage. The only other caveat is that you also must be attacking while drawing your weapon for it to work, but if you have a Gnomish Quickrazor *every* attack is done while drawing then sheathing the weapon, so...

Answer (score 2):

As someone who often played Rogues or Assassins, whenever that roll was not available, or I felt tired of it, I played a Ranger or a Monk.   If I wish to purposefully focus my attention on diplomacy or bluff skill, I might pick a bard.

Answer (score 1):

If you like a"sneaky" character, but not a rogue, i would say that the Complete Scoundrel is the book for you. It has PrCs, character options, feats and skill tricks for every class, but looking at these classes from another point of view, that of some one that relies on his cunning and his skills rather than his strength or his spellcasting. From fighters to clerics and monks to wizards and sorcerers, this book will have something for you i believe.

Answer (score 1):

The Beguiler or Spellthief are excellent options that both offer some overlap with the Rogue while having their own niche:

- The Beguiler is the dark side of the Bard, in many ways. They get trapfinding, Illusion & Enchantment spells, and a good amount of skill points.
- The Spellthief gets Trapfinding and Sneak Attack like a Rogue (a multiclass between them can even put you ahead a die!) while offering its own spin on things by being able to steal magic from opponents and use it against them.